# SQL Error: "There are no rows at position 0"

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am Trying to create a login form for my software and i keep getting this feedback as error; "There are no rows at postion 0".....This happens whenever i try to add a WHERE clause to my (SLELECT ProfileName, ProfilePassword from Profile) query (i.e 'sqlQuery' in code)......This is a snippet of my code

```
Public Sub sql_login(ByVal sqlQuery As String)
        Try
            'OPENING THE CONNECTION
            con.Open()
            'INITIALIZE YOUR COMMANDS
            'IT HOLDS THE DATA TO BE EXECUTED
            With cmd
                'PASS ON THE VALUE OF CON TO THE MYSQL COMMANND WHICH IS THE CONNECTION
                .Connection = con
                'THE FUNCTION OF THIS IS TO RETURN THE TEXT REPRESENTED BY A COMMAND OBJECT
                .CommandText = sqlQuery
            End With
            Dim dt = New DataTable
            'FOR RETRIEVING AND FILLING DATA IN THE TABLE
            Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con)
            'NEW TABLE IN THE DATATABLE

            da.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
            'SET THE TOTAL ROWS OF THE TABLE IN A VARIABLE[MAXROWS]
            Dim maxrows As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            con.Close()


            'preventing non empty values
            If Loginform.UsernameTextBox.Text <> "" And Loginform.PasswordTextBox.Text <> "" Then

                If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                    'CHECKING IF THE TOTAL ROWS OF THE TABLE ARE GREATER THAN 0

                    If maxrows > 0 Then
                        'THIS WILL BE NOTIFY YOU THAT WHO WOULD BE THE USER'S
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " & dt.Rows(1).Item(0) & "!" & ControlChars.NewLine & "You have sucessfully logged in.", "Login Confirmation")


                        'Tracing login time
                        Try
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO ProfileDates (ProfileName, LoginDates, ProfileID) VALUES ('" & Loginform.UsernameTextBox.Text & "',GetDate(),( SELECT TOP 1 profileID FROM Profile where ProfileName = '" & Loginform.UsernameTextBox.Text & "') )"

                            cmd.Connection = con
                            con.Open()
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            con.Close()

                            Suppliers_Module.LogoutBtn.Enabled = True
                            Suppliers_Module.LoginButton.Enabled = False
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            con.Close()
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                        End Try
                        end if
                      end if
                     end if
```

counting on you for your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the sql query?

Comment: Use parameters! You will be vulnerable to SQL Injection using that code.

Comment: Execute the query on your table and check, if it is not returning any rows then your datatable will be empty and hence no row at position 0, and if it is returning only one row then dt.Rows(1).Item(0) should be dt.Rows(0).Item(0)

Comment: More than likely your query isn't returning any data